# Click "Next" button on webpage using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a very simple webpage expecting to click on "NEXT" button after inputting an activation code. But i am not able to find the element by value/name  "next" .From the inspect element

```
<input type="submit" name="activationpage1:j_id_id18" value="Next &gt;&gt;" style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;text-align:center;" />
```

How can I achieve this in python code to click on the button named **`Next>>`**?

Comment: Search for an element with `name="activationpage1:j_id_id18"` or `value="Next &gt;&gt;"`.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried to click next with.

Comment: @Jortegafrom selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("http://acttivatexample.com/first/fast/actvn/")
activkey = driver.find_element_by_id("showActivation")
activkey.send_keys("mykey")

driver.find_element_by_name("next").click()

Comment: why do you use name `"next"` if in code you have `name="activationpage1:j_id_id18"` - you have to use `find_element_by_name("activationpage1:j_id_id18")`

Answer (score 2):

This element has name `"activationpage1:j_id_id18"` so use

```
driver.find_element_by_name("activationpage1:j_id_id18")
```

Or you can use `xpath` like

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@name="activationpage1:j_id_id18"]')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Next &gt;&gt;"]')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="submit"]')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif;font-size:11px;text-align:center;"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element with text as **`Next >>`** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name^='activationpage'][value^='Next'][type='submit']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@name,'activationpage') and starts-with(@value,'Next')][@type='submit']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```